Parenthetical phrases and listing commas
a:The acting was poor, no story line, and it was uninspired
b:The acting was poor (no story line) and it was uninspired.
c: The house was burning, curtains on fire, and smoke coming from the windows.
When a listing comma is being used to separate a single phrase within a given list, what is the distinction between this type of usage and a parenthetical phrase within a list that is often closed with a pair of brackets?
Online resources in relation to listing comma state a listing comma can be used to separate words and phrases which are usually shown as : Sarah bought, Apples, Oranges and Lemons from the store or for phrases:
He was good looking (if not a little rough around the edges) and fiery tempered.

Breakdown (b) is completely wrong - lack of a story line is "orthogonal" (unrelated) to poor acting, so it makes no sense to append that as parenthetical additional text associated with the first assertion. You might get away with the others in casual conversation, but strictly speaking they should be (a) The acting was poor, there was no story line, and it was uninspired, and (c) The house was burning, the curtains were on fire, and smoke was coming from the windows. In both cases it would probably be better to use a full stop instead of the first comma.

...and it makes no sense to include the word not in He was good looking (if a little rough around the edges) and fiery tempered.

There is no such thing as a "listing comma".  There are lists with the elements in the list separated by commas, and there are independent clauses separated by commas under certain circumstances.  The choice between semicolons and commas when separating independent clauses is a matter of style and convention, not grammar.

I would consider your sentences A and B ungrammatical.  The items in the list should be of the same grammatical type. The middle phrase should be a declaration with a subject and a verb, since it is flanked with items of that structure:

The acting was poor, it had no story line, and it was  uninspired.

Sentence C is not a list of "peer elements". The main clause is supplemented by a subordinate clause with coordination.  I'd simply add an article  (or "its") and remove the comma after and:

The house was burning, the curtains on fire and smoke coming from the windows.
The house was burning, its curtains on fire and smoke coming from the windows.

